# Rails association class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

i try to create an association class with Ruby on Rails but but it does not work.

I need to do this :

[image]

I have create my models but I'm not sure I did it right

Someone here can explain me from the beginning ?

```
class CreateJobsUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :jobs_users, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :jobs, index: true
      t.belongs_to :users, index: true
      t.integer :level
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is relation `many to many`, you can do this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_jobs
  has_many :jobs, through: :user_jobs
end

class UserJob < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :job
end

class Job < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_jobs
  has_many :users, through: :user_jobs
end
```

Detail about relation `many to many`, you can refer at:

[association many to many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Comment: Okay thank you i edit my post can you tell me if my migration to create table has good ? I never know if i need put a 'S' when i create my table

Comment: I assume your migration file should include singular form like:  t.belongs_to :job, index: true and t.belongs_to :user, index: true. For more details, you can check Rails Guides for associations, paragraph 2.4 The has_many :through Association. Link: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html